# Cakephp Find all DB error

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to make my index() function display only the ExpenseClaims belonging to that individual logged in user.

This is the function:

```
public function index() {
    $this->ExpenseClaim->recursive = 0;
    $currentUsersClaims = $this->ExpenseClaim->find('all', array('conditions' => array('ExpenseClaim.user_id ==' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
    $this->set('currentUsersClaims', $this->paginate());
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 3' at line 1

```
SQL Query: SELECT `ExpenseClaim`.`id`, `ExpenseClaim`.`user_id`, `ExpenseClaim`.`claim_status_id`, `ExpenseClaim`.`created`, `ExpenseClaim`.`modified`, `ExpenseClaim`.`approved`, `ExpenseClaim`.`approved_by`, `ExpenseClaim`.`date_submitted`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`group_id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`department_id`, `User`.`mileage_rate`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `ClaimStatus`.`id`, `ClaimStatus`.`name`, `ClaimStatus`.`created`, `ClaimStatus`.`modified` FROM `expenses`.`expense_claims` AS `ExpenseClaim` LEFT JOIN `expenses`.`users` AS `User` ON (`ExpenseClaim`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `expenses`.`claim_statuses` AS `ClaimStatus` ON (`ExpenseClaim`.`claim_status_id` = `ClaimStatus`.`id`) WHERE `ExpenseClaim`.`user_id` == 3
```

Forgive me as I'm probably missing somehting obvious but I'm pretty new to cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the error is because you're using a double equals `==`, which isn't valid in MySQL (single equals sign will do). Also I noticed you are trying to paginate those results, you can actually just pass the conditions you want to the paginate query:

```
$this->set(
    'currentUsersClaims',
    $this->paginate('ExpenseClaim', array(
        'ExpenseClaim.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ))
);
```

Be sure to read the [pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) section in the book.

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. Could you exmaple the ExpenseClaim.user_id = ? bit to me. Why = ? rather than just =

Comment: The question mark gets escaped/replaced with the second variable of the array, I have actually removed it now as for basic `var = var` it is not necessary, but it is needed for things like `BETWEEN starttime AND endTime` . [Read here fr more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions)

Answer (score 2):

`==` is not correct in a query n_n

your query should be

```
public function index() {
    $this->ExpenseClaim->recursive = 0;
    $currentUsersClaims = $this->ExpenseClaim->find('all', 
              array('conditions' => array('ExpenseClaim.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
    $this->set('currentUsersClaims', $this->paginate());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah drat, ofcourse, was in php mode! Thanks for that. However the fucntion is not returning the desired results (although the error is now gone). I only want to return expenseClaims belonging to the logged in user - do you know where I'm going wrong? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
'ExpenseClaim.user_id =='
```

should be

```
ExpenseClaim.user_id =
```

Edit: two answers while I was typing.... :)